# Appending retrieved data to python dictionary in django views

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I am trying to add data to the below mentioned dictionary d, and I am getting confused about where to begin. Given below is the segment of the code I am referring to.

```
            d={}
            vendor_choice = request.POST["inlineDefaultRadiosExample"]
            date_choice = request.POST["inlineDefaultRadiosExample1"]
            x = employee.objects.all()
            for i in x:
                if date_choice == 1:
                    d.update(transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendor_choice, emp_id = i.id, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)))
                elif date_choice == 2:
                    d.update(transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendor_choice, emp_id = i.id, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60)))
                else:
                    d.update(transaction.objects.filter(vendor_id=vendor_choice, emp_id = i.id, timestamp__gte = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)))
```

I want to append queries fetched by the transaction.objects.filter to the dictionary d. How to proceed with it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "append" ? A `dict` is not a `list`, it's a key:value mapping. Please edit your question to add an example of the expected result.

Comment: Try print print(d) outside for which will collect all updated data.

Comment: I meant add, have edited the question.

Comment: print(d) was just for debugging purposes, have removed it.

Comment: If you want to add in dictionary, simply update it, d.update({'queries': 'your query'}). Show your expected output, so you will get the answers. Your question is not much clear.

Comment: Hi Saroj. I am expecting output in the form of { {}, {}, {},... }, where each internal bracket contains the data obtained from my filter query.